# How do I unpack(unlist) a list without for loop in python?

Tags: python

Say, I have a variable a that has a list in it, it'll look something like this:

```
a = ['hello', 'there']
```

I wanted to unpack the list but I don't want to use for loop but I just can't figured out how to make it to work. I've tried:

```
def unpack(table):
    for i in table:
        return i


a = ['hello', 'there']

print(unpack(a))
```

I wanted it to print

```
hello, there
```

but it only prints hello
can someone help me with this?

but it only returns hello

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? Are you looking for e.g. `print(*a)`?

Comment: What do you want it to unpack to?

Comment: I depends what you actually want to do with it. The values have to go *somewhere*.

Comment: Maybe OP is expecting something like Perl, where arrays (not by a reference) act like `*a` ?

Comment: Or perhaps tuple unpacking, where you can assign the values rather than printing them? `x,y=a; print(x,'\n',y)`

Comment: I can't use x,y like that because I'm making the list randomly generated so I don't know how many strings are there in a list.

Comment: by unpack it means like this a =['test1', 'test2']
print(unpack(a)) #prints test1, test2 I know i can do this using for loop but i can't use it as it is in a format string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It only returns `Hello` because when you return a function, the function stops at that very first line. So, the next item will not be returned.
Also to unpack a list, just use `*`.

```
a = ['hello', 'there']

print(*a)
```

As asked, to write with comma, use: `print(', '.join(a))`

Comment: that gives me hello there i want it to have a comma between it like hello, there

Comment: @ShowcaserV4 Edited

Comment: `', '.join(a)` expects a `list` of `str` elements. Use `print(sep = ', ')` instead.